# Hangouts: How to make the phone dialer default (instead of the hangouts dialer)?

Tags: phone-app, google-hangouts

Following a recent Hangouts update, when using Android 5 on Nexus 5, in an SMS conversation with a contact, touching the "handset" icon automatically launches the Hangouts dialer, while I would like to use the default phone dialer instead.

I did not find any option to change this back to the previous behavior.  Is this possible at all?

Comment: Clear the default app for the dialer activity - see http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/42057/how-do-you-clear-share-actions-bound-to-copy-to-clipboard - where "[bound app]" is "Hangouts"

Comment: This does not work for me.  Dialer is still hangouts dialer.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't really need the hangouts dialer, you can disable it (as I believe it's now a separate app). Try: Settings -> Apps -> All -> Hangouts Dialer -> Disable.

If you can't disable Hangouts Dialer, you can uninstall it.  Hangouts will still function as normal.

Answer (score 0):

### Set default hangouts dialer to "Cellular Network (The default dialer you want)"

If you clear the cache on the dialer (hangouts dialer), it should prompt you the first time after that (when something triggers the dialers) asking which dialer to use.  You can select "always" on the regular dialer.  This will use your cell service, not Hangouts.

Comment: Hi Matt, please note that you're privileged to comment anywhere and comments, *et al*, are meant to seek clarification. Please use them before posting the answers. The reason is, answers are supposed to be for everyone, but not everyone can reply to you.

Comment: @Firelord Okay, But he person who asked the question can comment anywhere on the page there question is posted, thus the person who asked this question can comment on this answer

Comment: This does not work. I have no defaults set at the "Hangouts Dialer" app, yet it is always used to place a call from hangouts.

Comment: @Udi can you try this? 
If you clear the cache on the dialer, it should prompt you the first time after that (when something triggers the dialers) asking which dialer to use.  You can select "always" on the regular dialer.  This will use your cell service, not Hangouts.

Comment: @Matt07211 Clearing the hangout dailer's cache did not change anything.

Answer (score -1):

System Settings > Apps Manager > Hangouts > Clear default values
(exact wording may differ, I'm translating from my language)

Comment: Hi! This does not work. The dialer stays the hangouts dialer