# How to reset default share target on Cogi app, G3, Android 5.0?

Tags: default-applications, intents

I shared a [Cogi](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.cogi.mobile&hl=en) recording, and selected Gmail as the default share target. Now I want to unselect gmail as default. I can't find any place within the Cogi app itself to do it.

Also, I tried to clear app defaults via the Settings-->Apps and [Settings-->Apps-->Reset App Preferences](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/58055/503). In the Reset App Preferences, I don't see Cogi listed in the list of apps with any preferences to clear, and the Clear Preferences button is grayed out in the Apps menu entry on Cogi.

Anything I can do? (I haven't tried uninstalling/reinstalling Cogi yet)