# What am I supposed to do with Bug reports captured?

Tags: bugs, 7.0-nougat

From time to time I get a notification on my phone which says:

```
Bug report #1 captured
Tap to share your bug report
```

When I tap, it warns me about the possibility of sensitive information being in the report.  I tap on "Ok" to continue.

But now, instead of the report being submitted somewhere automatically, like it would under something like Windows or Mac OS X, it pops up a "Share with" prompt, asking me how I want to share it.   I have no idea, I don't even know what caused the bug report!

The choices I see are `Gmail` (who am I supposed to send it to, especially given that I don't know what the report is even about?), `Add to Dropbox` (what good would that be?), `Android Beam` (never used this, but it sounds like maybe I would need to be in the same room as Android developer for this to be useful), and `Save to Drive` (again, seems about as useless as adding to my Dropbox).

I'm not even sure why I'm being prompted to do this, given the complete lack of instruction on what I should be doing.

Update: I tried e-mailing the report to myself. The bug report contained an empty (black) image, and a zip file containing a 16.4MB log file (which appeared to just be a dump of various process info - I didn't look at the whole thing due to length, but I couldn't find any obvious indication of what the problem was) and a FS directory containing a path FS/data/tombstones containing 10 separate files ranging between one month and one year old (nothing from today!).  The newest of these files appear to be system related (/system/bin/rild, com.android.nfc, system/bin/netmgrd, ...)

Comment: You'd want to email it, when you click Gmail, does it auto-populate the TO field with an email address?

Comment: @RMarkwald That's a good question.  I actually decided to e-mail it to myself just to try to figure out what app had the bug, and I don't recall now if there was a pre-populated to address or not - if there was, it was my own.

Comment: Is it the same as this [What does it mean with bug report captured in android tablet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18648353/what-does-it-mean-with-bug-report-captured-in-android-tablet)

Comment: @kirodge Oh! Maybe.  I don't recall pressing power + volume up + volume down buttons, but I suppose it could have happened accidentally.  I was under the impression that a bug report would be generated by a crash or something like that.

Comment: Quick developer perspective: some apps do have built-in automatic crash reporting. The Android bug report feature is basically useless to app developers because it doesn't include any information specific to the app.

Comment: Related: [How can I share my bug report with Android devs?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/154887/44325)

Answer (score 1):

Where you *share* the bug report depends entirely up to you. A bug report can be generated regardless if there is an issue/error/crash or not.

Usually, bug reports are needed by developers and/or supports in order to find more details in pinpointing a specific issue. The bug report is essential since it provides a *lot* of details about the device from which the error/issue is occuring.

How you share it depends on how you are communicating with the developer or support, it's usually just through email, but it's also safe to save it via your own Cloud Storage account (e.g. Google Drive, Dropbox), then share the download URL.